# Filter Geometry (Lat, Lng) Distance by kilometers with Entity Framework Core and MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, geospatial, spatial-query, nettopologysuite

I used the artice from https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/modeling/spatial to start and use

- Entity Framework Core
- MS SQL
- NetTopologySuite.Core 1.15.3

I have a class City with IGeometry type. It was automatically created because i created the table in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[City] (
    [Location][sys].[geography] NULL,
);

public partial class City
{
    public IGeometry Location { get; set; }
}
```

At first i created the data

```
GeoAPI.Geometries.IGeometryFactory geometryFactory = NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(srid: 4326);
GeoAPI.Geometries.IPoint point = geometryFactory.CreatePoint(new GeoAPI.Geometries.Coordinate((double)c.Lat, (double)c.Lng));
City city = new City();
city.Location = point;
```

In the database the location is now like 0xE6100000010CCC7A319413CD2A4044696FF085314A40

Now i want to Query. I want all cities near a searchCity:

```
from city in cityRepository.Table
where city.Location.Distance(searchCity.Location) < 20 // 20 kilometers
select city;
```

The problem is here, that the calculated distance is very small. For example the city to another city with 300 kilometers distance has a calculated distance of about 4.
When i read the documentation the distance is in degrees. But i need to filter by kilometers.
There is also something about ProjNet4GeoAPI in the documentation. But i not want to calculate after i query. I want to get only the cities inside a radius with the query.

Comment: Taking your code out of it, what if in the database you interrogate your data some? Does your table have only one column? If so, how do you plan on addressing a given row? That is, how do you know that one row is, frex, Amsterdam and another London? Either way, take two of the geography values from your table and do something like `@a.STDistance(@b)` on them (where @a and @b are the two geography values from your table).

Comment: The table has more rows (id, name, zip, location). I already have the id of one city and want all cities in a distance. One row is has the name Amsterdam and another London and other other... STDistance is only used in sql or? But i want to filter with linq. If there is no better way, i can make a stored procedure for find all cityId with STDistance and later use in the linq query.

Comment: In the ideal, you use linq. What I'm suggesting is in the interest of debugging. In your write-up, you mentioned getting back a different distance than you expected so I'm trying to take variables out of the equation.

Comment: Now i changed the query to make it easy and get bigger distance. But it is still wrong.
Distance: 419164.16016929084  
Lat1: 53.4594404510  
Lng1: 9.9791784448  
Lat2: 50.0761999000  
Lng2: 8.2307290000
Lat1 in db: 0xE6100000010C71BA8AE056F5234093C0D7F1CEBA4A40
Lat2 in db: 0xE6100000010C427A8A1C22762040AF3A17EBC0094940

Comment: It seems right to me. I took your two lat/long coordinate pairs and plugged them into https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gccalc.shtml (after converting them to degrees/minutes/seconds) and got 394 km while SQL is giving me 419164 m = 419 km. That seems within the margin of error to me and can probably be accounted for in the NOAA website likely using Haversine whereas SQL is accounting for the eccentricity of the globe. What are you expecting to come back?

Comment: I expecting the 394 km. Is that possible to get a better result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199340/discussion-between-ben-thul-and-xeddon).